How to visualize a submodule of a model in pytorch?
Understand from this question  that we are able to visualize a net in pytorch. However, if a network is very big and complex, we might want to zoom in and visualize only a specific part of it. Is there a quick way to improve from the solutions in the above question and achieve this?
I have tried to take components of the model by 'model.xxx' and plug it back to the torchview.draw_graph() fucntion (hoping it can work, but apparently not)
